# BxSlider Thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I can not understand how to make thumbnails. I copy the code from the
example, but the slider does not work. Сan someone show full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make thumbnails but they can be hard coded in the script for eg:

In script

```
$('.slider').bxSlider({
auto: true,
pager: true,
controls:false,
speed: 2000,
pause: 8000,
mode: 'fade',
buildPager: function(slideIndex){
  switch (slideIndex){
    case 0:
      return '<a href="">Pager1</a>';
    case 1:
      return '<a href="">Pager2</a>';
    case 2:
      return '<a href="">Pager3</a>';
    case 3:
      return '<a href="">Pager4</a>';
  }
}   
});
```

and in html create 'ul' with id = slider with four 'li'.

Hope this help.